# socket.io is not working in entire component ! its work only inside a function in vue js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, sockets, socket.io

```
<form class="login-form" @submit.prevent ="Login">

  <div class="form-inner">
    <h1>Login to Chat</h1>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input 
     v-model="username" type="text" 
      
      placeholder="Please enter your username..." />
    <input 
      type="submit" 
      value="Login" />
  </div>
</form>
```

import io from 'socket.io-client';

export default {

data(){

```
return{
socket : io("http://localhost:3000"),
  inputMessage:"",
 username:"",
 isLogin:false,
 messages:[],
 users:[],
};
```

},

methods:{

joinServer(){

```
this.socket.on("loggedIn",data=>{
    console.log("one");
  this.messages = data.messages;
  this.users = data.users;
  this.socket.emit('newuser',this.username);
 console.log("one");
});
this.socket.on("userOnline",user =>{
    this.users.push(user);
  });
    this.socket.on("userleft",user =>{
    this.users.splice(this.user.indexof(user),1);
  });
  this.socket.on("msg",message =>{
    this.messages.push(message);
  });
```

},

Login(){

```
  this.joinServer();
  this.isLogin = true;
```

}
}

its only work when I use socket as variable inside a function(joinserver)

joinServer(){

let socket = io("http://localhost:3000");

```
socket.on("loggedIn",data=>{
    console.log("one");
  this.messages = data.messages;
  this.users = data.users;
  this.socket.emit('newuser',this.username);
 console.log("one");
});
socket.on("userOnline",user =>{
    this.users.push(user);
  });
    socket.on("userleft",user =>{
    this.users.splice(this.user.indexof(user),1);
  });
  socket.on("msg",message =>{
    this.messages.push(message);
  });
```

}
and so  I cannot use it in another function

Comment: Try setting a value to `socket` inside the `mounted` method (https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#mounted).

Comment: already did  it its not working i also try to make it global by so that I can use it like 'this.$socket' but I did not work

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by not working? did you get errors in the console? Also please try setting the value for `this.socket` inside `joinServer` and then using it (maybe it's being overwritten somewhere).

Comment: Not working means connection is established but its not doing any operations other than connection